# Projects with identical configurations are run differently

Tags: travis-ci

I've setup two Java projects with the same `.travis.yml` file.

One works fine, one fails, because it appears that they're using different workers. One fails with

- Fails: https://travis-ci.org/prism/Bedrock/jobs/110693590

  "Sorry, but JDK 'openjdk8' is not known."
- Works: https://travis-ci.org/prism/Prism/jobs/110620073

Another, using `oraclejdk8` fails with checkstyle errors, yet checkstyle when run locally has no problems.

I can't find any information as to why the workers would be different, and `openjdk8` is unknown in one vm, but not a problem in another.

Our config:

```
dist: trusty
install: true
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
script: gradle build
```

Comment: Try restarting the build, Travis sometimes bugs out like that

Comment: It's happened a dozen times in a row.